# Random Forest model

Tags: performance, algorithm, r

I am new in machine learning methods and I am trying to use a Random Forest regression. I want to explain the influence of my variables on the variable "one" and I have the following code:

```
library (raster)
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
facts= trainControl(method="cv", number=10,savePredictions = TRUE)

in_train= createDataPartition(example_data, p=.66, list=FALSE) 
train_dt=example_data[in_train,]
test_dt=example_data[-in_train,] 

dt_cor<-cor(in_train)
hcor<-findCorrelation(dt_cor,0.90)

train_dt_clean=train_dt[, -hcor]
test_dt_clean=test_dt[, -hcor] 

my_model = train(one ~ .,
data=train_dt_clean,ntree=800,method="rf",metric="Rsquared",trControl=facts,importance = TRUE)

my_model$resample[with(my_model$resample, order(Resample)), ]
```

Apart from removing the multicollinearity and removing/adding parameters, what can I do to improve my model? How can I understand if my model can further be improved?

[Example data here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RIGrtI2FmQmTPc139ebSRVOrQbS-0BBr/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please revise the title of your post: per the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), the title should _"State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it."_.

Comment: @VisualMelon, thank you for your notice. I will learn how to better ask questions!